# NPM configuration to skip vulnerabilities audit for devDependencies on install

Tags: node.js, npm, audit

Is it possible to configure npm to skip audit of vulnerabilities for `devDependencies` when running command `npm install`?

Answer (score 22):

You can skip auditing at all by adding the `--no-audit` flag.

```
npm install --no-audit
```

If you want this to apply to devDependencies only, you can run it this way:

```
npm install --no-audit --only=dev
```

If you want this to apply to production dependencies only, you can run it this way:

```
npm install --no-audit --only=prod
```

Answer (score 16):

Since this is a first result when you try to google for a way to disable audit, let's post a more convenient solution for more general case.

You can skip auditing altogether by using `npm config`:

```
npm config set audit false
```

And to reduce pesky noise even more:

```
npm config set fund false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --disableNodeJS --nodeAuditSkipDevDependencies
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply just use the command

```
npm audit --prod
```

And to ignore a particular package use

```
npm audit --ignore packageName
```

To know more about it you can visit this link - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20564.

Comment: Thank you, I know about `npm audit --prod`. I was asking if there is a global npm configuration available to skip dev dependencies auditing on `npm install`.